# Are there any credit cards that run Java?

Tags: java

When installing Java I noticed credit cards listed among the devices that run Java. Is this true? How do they work?

[image]

Comment: Or Smart cards in general. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card

Comment: That's going to have to be one very quick boot time to run the code on the card. One hopes it is possible

Comment: A stackoverflow.com question perhaps?

Comment: @therobyouknow Definitely not on topic for Stack Overflow. There's no (programming) problem to be solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a Card API that runs on smartcard chips on credit cards.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/overview/index.html